# How to compare with a string array and string

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I want to compare one string with the string array because I need to match a phone number if it starts with some specific number then I need to do something.

Here is what I'm doing now. But I want to make this simpler.

```
string[] startNumList = new string[] {"4", "5", "6", "7", "8" };
foreach (string x in startNumList)
{
      if(request.ReferenceNumber.StartsWith(x))
       {
            //do something
       }
 }
```

I was jut wondering if this is possible to do the same with one line LINQ.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Linq will actually loop the array in the same way you´re currently doing it. It only hides this away from you.

Comment: Why? LINQ would have to iterate the array as well.

Comment: *LINQ and without looping* is meaningless since Linq internally loops

Comment: If it loops internally I don't mind as I need to minimize the lines of code as well. Thanks

Comment: What is `//do something`?

Comment: You could do `foreach(var element in startsNumList.Where(x => request.ReferenceNumber.StartsWith(x))) // do something`, but this will also loop your array.

Comment: `if(startNumList.Any(s => request.ReferenceNumber.StartsWith(s)))`

Comment: @KennethK.: it's a comment..! `lol` does it matter ?

Comment: Don't minimize lines of code just to do so.  Optimize for readability.  The poor sucker who has to maintain the code might well be you.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. I just like to ask pointless questions in the comment section of Stack. It's how I get my kicks...Depending on what you are doing there, maybe you call `.ToList().ForEach(...)`, maybe you call `.Select(...)`, maybe you do something else. If you're not going to post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then why should anyone take the time to help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give a definitive answer to this sort of question, but I'd go with this:

```
var matchingStartNumber = startNumList.FirstOrDefault(x => request.ReferenceNumber.StartsWith(x));
if (matchingStartNumber != null)
{
    // Do stuff with startNum
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the foreach loop you can use "Any" method from Linq to see if any items in your "startNumList" match the condition.

```
if(startNumList.Any(x => request.ReferenceNumber.StartsWith(x)))
{
                //do something
}
```

Comment: The downside to this approach is if you need to know which value of 'x' matched within your logic, which is likely, then you've got to query again

Comment: @LordWilmore that’s true. This approach is only viable if it’s the same logic regardless of which number the phone number starts with.